# My reference only shows half

Tags: bibliographies

Here is a website reference in my `.bib` file ...

```
@MISC{Peston2010,
AUTHOR = {Peston, Robert},
TITLE = {The Digital Economy Bill},
URL = {www.news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/technology/8604602.stm},
DATE = {9},
MONTH {April},
YEAR = {2010},
ACCESSED = {8 February 2012}
}
```

When I compile and display my PDF, it only shows "Robert Peston. The digital economy bill"   It does not show the URL, Date, Month, Year and Accessed. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I spent a while sorting this out and decided to consult help.

Also,  when I compile, I get a small error "Overfull \hbox (183.18742pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--10". I am quite new to LaTex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: this sounds like it's dependent on the `\bibliographystyle` you're using in your `.tex` file.  what is it?

Comment: Hi Barbara. In my .tex file I'am using...

\bibliography{myref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\printindex

to get my references from .bib file.

Comment: @user11998: You can edit your question to include additional information.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a modern `.bst` file; `plain.bst` is not going to cut it, I'm afraid. In `plain` and the other "classic" BibTeX style files, the only fields contained in a `misc` entry that are printed out are `author`, `title`, `howpublished`, `date`, and `note`. All other fields -- including `url` and `accessed` -- are *ignored*. Hence the need for a more recent bibliography style.

Which bibliography style *should* you choose? Since you haven't indicated what your formatting requirements are, I can't give any definitive advice. You may want to start out with the `plainnat` bibliography style. (This means, by the way, that you will also need to load the `natbib` package, but you may be doing so already.) You should probably also be loading the `url` package to let LaTeX find convenient line break points in a long URL string.

By the way, the `date` field in a `misc` entry is a bit unusual. (At least that's the case when it's processed by `plainnat.`) For your purposes, I think it's best if you omit the `date` field entirely and, instead, include the day-of-the-month information in the `month` field; i.e., set `month = "9 April"` for the entry at hand.

Be aware that the `misc` entry (at least when used with the `plainnat` style) does *not* recognize a field named `accessed`. However, things will work out well if you (i) replace the `accessed` field name with `note` and (ii) place the word "Accessed" inside the `note` field's argument. Assuming, then, that you go with `plainnat` or a similar bibliography style, the bib entry should probably look something like this:

```
@misc{Peston2010,
  author = "Peston, Robert",
  title  = "The Digital Economy Bill",
  url    = "www.news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/technology/8604602.stm",
  year   = 2010,
  month  = "9 April",
  note   = "Accessed 8 February 2012",
}
```

With this entry stored in the file `myref.bib`, say, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\citet{Peston2010}, \citep{Peston2010}
\bibliography{myref} % myref.bib contains the entry keyed to 'Peston2010'
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

Two final comments: (i) If you don't want BibTeX to lowercase the words in the `title` field, you should enclose the words in question in curly braces. (ii) If you want the citations generated by `natbib`'s `\citet` and `\citep` commands to use round parentheses rather than square brackets, load the `natbib` package with the option "round", as in `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`.

Comment: Hi Mico, I'm using \bibliographystyle{plain} style. I pasted your example. And it worked, but the URL doesn't show up. I find the URL a big problem because all the references on websites do not display URL. And when I compile, I get a small error "Overfull \hbox (183.18742pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--10".     I'm quite new to Latex.

Comment: @user11998: I've applied a couple of corrections to my answer and also added a MWE and its output. I hope this will help you get you on your way.